# Python rglob("*") vs glob("*)

Tags: python, shutil, pathlib

I am trying to move a bunch of files with "V1.2" in the name to an archive folder. It seems to be working fine with the following code:

```
for folder in copyPath.glob("*"):
    for subfolder in folder.glob("*"):
        for content in subfolder.glob("*"):
            if "V1.2" in content.name:
                shutil.move(content ,Path(subfolder,"Archive"))
```

However, the following code with `rglob("*V1.2*")`, python just creates an "Archive" named extentionless file into the archive folder. Why is that?

```
for file in copyPath.rglob("*V1.2*"):
    shutil.move(file,Path(file.parent,"Archive"))
```

Regards,
AS

Comment: Did you try to check what the values of `file` are each time through the loop? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: What does "*an 'Archive' named extentionless file*" mean?

Comment: @Green绿色 it creates a file called "Archive" in the archive folder.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes it return the correct file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state that the following code creates a file named "Archive" in the archive folder:

```
for file in copyPath.rglob("*V1.2*"):
    shutil.move(file,Path(file.parent,"Archive"))
```

[shutil.move](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) only moves your files into a directory if the directory already exists. Otherwise, it'll move (rename) your *file*. I guess that `Path(file.parent, "Archive")` is not a directory, so every file matching the condition is moved into a file called "Archive", each file overwriting the previous one.

The fix should be simple:

```
for file in copyPath.rglob("*V1.2*"):
    target = Path(file.parent, "Archive")
    if target.is_file():
        raise ValueError(f"Invalid directory: {target} is a file!")  # safety check to avoid overwriting files and data loss

    if not target.is_dir():
        target.mkdir(parents=True)  # <- this should solve your problem

    shutil.move(file, target)
```